# How to sort groovy list correctly

Tags: java, groovy

I have the following list:

```
    def l1 = [1, 3, 2, 'b', '-', '-', 'a']
```

I am sorting the list by the following:

```
   l1.sort(false)
```

I get sorted list as [1, 2, 3, '-', '-', 'a', 'b'] but how can I get the sorted list as ['-', '-', 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l1.sort{ a,b-> a.toString() <=> b.toString() }
```